# Имеется ли план развития платформы StackOverflow?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange

Существует ли какой-либо план развития платформы StackOverflow? Хотелось бы узнать что планируется к внедрению, что не стоит ждать в обозримом будущем, что в данный момент тестируется и т.д. и т.п..

Ни для кого не секрет, что многострадальные спойлеры (сворачивание больших листингов кода) не могут реализовать уже очень продолжительное время. Выбора вопросов в ленте только с метками на которые подписан пользователь нет. Официального Desktop-клиента нет. Ну это так, как говорится, на вскидку... Уверен, что если спросить людей, которые здесь постоянно, то наберётся ещё пару десятков "хотелок"...

Заходя на сайт/репозиторий/readme.md популярных библиотек/фреймворков и т.п., как правило можно узнать о планах на будущее разработчиков, но SO ничего не публикует (либо это как-то хорошо спрятано, либо я не вижу/не туда жмакаю). Можно ли узнать о планах на будущее платформы, но не витиевато и абстрактно, а как можно более конкретно и предметно?

Comment: Если сюда приплюсовать все вопросы связанные с локализацией, там на сотни наберётся :D Родмепа у них никогда не было и вряд ли будет, т.к. с планированием сложно всё. Плюс, насколько я помню, сейчас в приоритете платный SO for Teams (в силу финансовых трудностей компании, вероятно), так что хотелки сообщества ушли на второй план.

Comment: @Suvitruf на мой взгляд, платный сервис тем более должен иметь roadmap, т.к. для корпоративных клиентов, которые решат завязать свою инфраструктуру на SO for Teams, необходимо иметь чёткое понимание планов по развитию сервиса.

Comment: Я на MSE часто спрашивал у сотрудников про Roadmap и т.п, они его боятся давать, т.к. в случае срывов сроков (а они постоянны), сообщество негодует. Поэтому они решили не шарить родмеп и сроки не называть.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну можно-же и без сроков объяснить сообществу, что, к примеру, песочницы для .Net языков в ближайшем будущем не планируется, Git - можете вообще не ждать, а вот автозаполнение для популярных языков программирования, при наборе кода, в приоритете... Жаль конечно, если всё так, как Вы говорите...

Comment: `многострадальные спойлеры (сворачивание больших листингов кода) не могут реализовать уже очень продолжительное время` — ну так простыни кода и не приветствуются (требуется *минимальный самодостаточный пример*). Вот и не делают за ненадобностью.

Comment: @Arhad не могу с Вами согласиться. И всё таки хотелось услышать не почему не делают то или иное, а план развития.

Answer (score 2):

План, безусловно, имеется. Без какого-либо плана невозможно что-то серьёзно развивать. Другое дело, что план этот не является публичным для достаточно дальней перспективы. В более короткой перспективе на мета сайтах: [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) и [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) с метками [[announcements]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements) и [[announcement]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/announcement) соответственно. Однако, довольно часто в подобных сообщениях уже сообщается о некоторой выкаченной в продакшен функциональности с предложением публиковать в качестве ответов те или иные замечания (выявленные баги) и предложения по улучшению реализации. Помимо этого есть красные метки типа [status-*] для мета сайтов, где в том числе можно найти и [отклонённые](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) или [отложенные](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) задачи. При этом никаких реальных сроков (для отложенных задач) ждать в таких сообщениях не стоит: иногда они решаются быстро, иногда - висят годами.

Comment: Т.е. если по-русски, то ответ "нет"...