# У нового инструмента фильтров нет официального объявления на мете

Tags: поддержка, предложение, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где комментарии администрации? Где релиз? Где описание функционала? Что-бы хотя бы переводчики нормально подготовились, а то даже [локализации нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9046/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85).

Там конечно все легко и понятно, но было бы лучше, если бы все был пост.

Comment: Мы уже много лет просим, чтоб они строки заранее добавляли и предупреждали локализованные сайты. Но, думаю, этого не будет никогда )

Comment: С официальными объявлениями о новом функционале в целом на Stack Exchange беда. Обычно можно следить за тегами [featured] и [announcements] на метамете, но в данном случае [объявление о новых фильтрах](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327816/custom-question-lists-april-status-update) никак не выделено.

Comment: @defaultlocale писал [недавно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9006/176217) об этом. Как-то не зашло никому :)

Comment: Да, все это немного печально

Comment: А где этот новый инструмент фильтров? Судя по скрину, он находится на странице вопросов, но у меня ничего такого нет.

Comment: @XelaNimed https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORu0W.png

Comment: @AntonSorokin https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvZuv.png Нет у меня...

Comment: @XelaNimed возможно в профиле на enSO или SE надо включить бета функции

Comment: @AntonSorokin если это beta, то возможно поэтому и нет объявления на мете, а также присутствуют проблемы с локализацией?

Comment: @XelaNimed это проблема не только для беты